# SSIS Get Table Name

Tags: xml, ssis, schema, oledb, script-component

What I want to accomplish is to get the table name where the Error Description Occurs.
What Im thinking is to get the component name of the OLEDB Destination(occupancy/attachedStructures), but I dont know how to do it, or are there any other ways to do it.

Here is my sample Diagram based from the steps [here](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/08/08/1969.aspx)
 
[image: SSIS Diagram]

Comment: "get the table name where the Error Description Occurs". Do you mean if an error occurs anywhere in your package you want to find out the table name? Is the script component in this diagram meant to be calling `GetErrorDescription`? Please name it so. What is the actual problem - what happens when an error occurs, does it not capture the error as expected? You need to supply a lot more information, including what the actual problem is.

Comment: Script Component Gets the Error Description and when i captures it those Errors were stored in the Errors DB.

I want to know if the error comes from occupancy or attachedStructures

Comment: If you enable logging in your package, it will tell you in there. i.e. it will write a log and indicate an error against that exact task. Go to SSIS/Logging in your package and enable logging.

Comment: yep I got that, but How am I gonna include that to insert into my Errors DB?

Comment: Is there any reason you need a special error table? Any reason you can't you use the native SSIS one? If you must use your own, I know you can put event handlers against your tasks and log the errors in there.